# Why does Integrate return an unexpected imaginary solution?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-value

When I calculate the value of the following integral using `Integrate`, I receive an unexpected imaginary solution. I am using Mathematica 11.3.0.

```
Integrate[
  9.257208212146324`*^14 Cos[6.0415243338265245` x] Cos[30.207621669132624`x] 
    Sin[42.290670336785674` x] U[5, 0] U[7, 0],
  {x, 0, 0.52}
]
(* Out: (1.15009*10^14 - 0.0425289 I) U[5, 0] U[7, 0] *)
```

Comment: It seems to be on the order of round-off error (relative magnitude ~ `$MachineEpsilon`).

Answer (score 2):

This is due to precision issues with the floating-point math. Always use exact numbers with exact commands such as `Integrate`, else it might use numerical methods internally.

```
integrand = 
  9.257208212146324`*^14 Cos[6.0415243338265245` x] 
    Cos[30.207621669132624` x] Sin[42.290670336785674` x];
integrand0 = SetPrecision[integrand, Infinity]
```

[image: integrand at high precision]

```
 Integrate[integrand0 , {x, 0, 52/100}]
```

[image: results of integration]

```
N[%]
(* Out: 1.15009*^14 *)
```

[image: numerical estimate of those results]

Comment: Interesting/bizarre: ``SetPrecision[
 Hold@Integrate[
   9.257208212146324`*^14 Cos[6.0415243338265245` x] Cos[
     30.207621669132624` x] Sin[42.290670336785674` x] U[5, 0] U[7, 
     0], {x, 0, 0.52}],
 16]``

Comment: @MichaelE2  The main issues appears to be `U[5, 0] U[7, 0]`.  When omitted, the integration is performed, although with the strange warning message about the precision of the argument function.

Comment: @bbgodfrey For me the main issue is that the evaluation leaked outside of `Hold`. I would think that could be considered a bug. Consider `SetPrecision[Hold[Sin[1]], 16]` in which `Sin` is not evaluated. Evaluation also leaks if I replace `Hold` by `HoldComplete`.

Comment: @MichaelE2  I see your point.  Thanks.